# Is there an HTML 5 equivalent to Adobe P2P Flash video?

Tags: flash, html, video, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Is there any way to do something like Adobe P2P video with HTML5 and no Adobe software?

I don't like Flash.

Comment: Maybe you should change the title. Its a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.

While there exists early drafts for W3C [Device](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/) APIs, including [Media Capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/), most lack implementations as of yet.